# How to find the pair of rows where the difference of columns value is maximum group by some column value

Tags: sql, h2

I've a table similar to the following,

[image]

I want to find the pair of centers whose Performance difference is maximum for every session. So, I want a table like the following,

[image]

I'm struggling to form the correct query for h2 database.

Comment: This question has a better (faster) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879412/my-query-is-taking-too-long-to-finish-for-finding-the-pair-of-rows-where-the-dif/58879652#58879652).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could self-join the table and use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select 
    t1.session,
    t1.center center1,
    t2.center center2,
    t1.performance - t2.performance performance
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.session = t2.session
where t1.performance - t2.performance = (
    select max(t11.performance - t22.performance)
    from mytable t11
    inner join mytable t22 on t11.session = t22.session
    where t11.session = t1.session
)
```

Or you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t1.session,
        t1.center center1,
        t2.center center2,
        t1.performance - t2.performance performance,
        rank() over(partition by t1.session order by t1.performance - t2.performance desc)rn
    from mytable t1
    inner join mytable t2 on t1.session = t2.session
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Could you please explain about t1, t2, t11, t22 tables. I've only one table. Thank you.

Comment: @ManojBanik: these are *table aliases*. Since we are self-joining the table, we need aliases to disambiguate.

Comment: Okay, now my table actually another query, I'm trying to replace t1,t2 with that query, and my query is little long as well, I'm having difficulty to track, exactly what to replace. Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't worry about the `t*` aliases. You need to replace all occurences of `mytable` with your query. The second query might be simpler to modify, since `mytable` occurs only once... I think recent versios of h2 support window functions.

Comment: First one just works, Thank you, I didn't replace all occurrences, Thank you.

Comment: One problem, I'm getting many outputs for session 1, i supposed to get one result from each session.

Comment: @ManojBanik: the only thing I can think that could generate multiple records per session is that there are ties in `performance`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202165/discussion-between-manoj-banik-and-gmb).

Answer (score 1):

H2 can be a bit tricky.  I think this does what you want:

```
select t.session,
       max(case when performance = min_performance then center end) as center_1,
       max(case when performance = max_performance then center end) as center_2,
       (max_performance - min_performance) as performance_difference
from (select t.*
             min(performance) over (partition by session) as min_performance,
             max(performance) over (partition by session) as max_performance
      from t
     ) t
group by t.session, min_performance, max_performance;
```

Comment: It does not work I'm getting errors, the table I'm talking - actually another query that generate a table similar to this. Now I'm trying to wrap/sandwich my query with THIS query, but I'm getting syntax errors.

Comment: There are several t's, could you please take a look at the queries. Thank you. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @ManojBanik . . . `t` in the `from` clause is your table name.

Comment: I understood, now in my case 't' itself a query, I just replace the 't' with the query only once at "from t", Right?

Comment: @ManojBanik . . . Then `t` would be an alias for the query.  Or the name of the CTE.

Comment: Still having syntax errors, but my query part (which I use to replace t) is okay as it works with the top one in this page.