# My query is taking too long to finish for finding the pair of rows where the difference of columns value is maximum group by another column

Tags: java, sql, h2

Say, I've a table like this:

[image]

I want to find the pair of Centers whose Performance difference is highest for each session, like this:

[image]

I have the following query,

```
select 
    t1.session,
    t1.center center1,
    t2.center center2,
    t1.performance - t2.performance performance
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.session = t2.session
where t1.performance - t2.performance = (
    select max(t11.performance - t22.performance)
    from mytable t11
    inner join mytable t22 on t11.session = t22.session
    where t11.session = t1.session
)
```

It works but took long time, few minutes for a table of 20 columns and 200 rows. **How can I modify the query to achieve the same output faster?**

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
    and [QUERY PLAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: What is your H2 version?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: If the row (1-B-88) was like (1-B-96), in the output the value of center1 would be A or B?

Comment: Can the difference be negative? or  you want absolute value?

Comment: H2 version 1.4.197. I want absolute difference, Running time is 7 minutes for a table of 23 columns, 232 rows.

Comment: Can you use ROW_NUMBER?  I read is available since  V1.4.198,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
        t1.session,
        t1.center center1,
        t2.center center2,
        t1.performance - t2.performance performance
    from mytable t1
    inner join mytable t2 
       on t1.session = t2.session
    WHERE t1.performance = (SELECT MAX(performance) 
                            FROM mytable t3 WHERE t3.session = t1.session)
      AND t2.performance = (SELECT MIN(performance) 
                            FROM mytable t3 WHERE t3.session = t2.session)

     // Im thinking this will solve the border case when performance is a tie 
     // and difference 0 will return 2 rows

     AND (CASE WHEN t1.performance = t2.performance 
               THEN CASE WHEN t1.center < t2.center
                         THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                    END
               ELSE 1
          END) = 1
```

As long as you have an index on `performance` and `session` should be fine.

Comment: WOW! this is real quick, just within sec. (from 7 minutes.) Thank you.

Comment: Check my update for border case. Remember mark the answer as correct if solve the problem. And remember create index if table will growth bigger.

Comment: Previous one worked, this version doesn't. it says: Column "T1.SESSION" not found;

Comment: If you check edit history I didn't edit just add more lines

Comment: I edited (commented out some line that creates problem).

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select session, center1, center2, performance
from (select t1.center as center1, t2.center as center2,
             (t1.performance - t2.performance) as performance,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.session order by (t1.performance - t2.performance) desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t1 join
           mytable t2
           on t1.session = t2.session
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or for better performance.  The maximum difference is the maximum minus the minimum.  You want the centers, here is a method without subqueries:

```
select session,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then center end) as center1,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then center end) as center2,
       max(performance) - min(performance)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by session order by performance) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by session order by performance desc) as seqnum_desc
      from mytable t
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)
group by session
```

Comment: my h2 doesn't support the row_number, I'm getting syntax errors.

Comment: @ManojBanik . . . It is supported starting with V1.4.198.  Here is the documentation:  http://www.h2database.com/html/functions-window.html.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by session and taking the group's min and max performance seems logical.
The actual centers unfortunately need a subquery/join here.

```
select g.session as Session,
    (select min(center) from mytable
     where session = g.session and performance = g.maxim) as Center1,
    (select min(center) from mytable
     where session = g.session and performance = g.minim) as Center2,
    g.maxim - g.minim as Performance
from (select 
        t1.session,
        min(t1.performance) as minim,
        max(t1.performance) as maxim
    from mytable t1
    group by t1.session)
    as g
```

Ensure an index on session and performance.

Comment: I'm getting this messages: "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Scalar subquery contains more than one row;"

Comment: The column query did not yield 1 row, for session & performance. added min to take one of the centers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(session) * from (
select  t1.session, t1.center, t2.center, 
(case when t1.performance > t2.performance then (t1.performance-t2.performance) else (t2.performance-t1.performance))as performance_diff 
from mytable t1, mytable t2 
where t1.session=t2.session and t1.center!=t2.center) as T1 order by session,performance_diff desc limit 1;
```

Comment: H2 database doesn't support this query, I'm getting this message: "H2 Database Connection: runtime exception: Unable to prepare query: Syntax error in SQL statement". @Sagar

Comment: @ManojBanik this query is based on Postgresql.