# How to keep a h2 database query SHORT when a part of it repeats few times?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, h2

I've the following query, the details were discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879412/my-query-is-taking-too-long-to-finish-for-finding-the-pair-of-rows-where-the-dif/58879652#58879652):

```
select 
    t1.session, t1.center center1, t2.center center2, 
    t1.performance - t2.performance performance
    from mytable t1
    inner join mytable t2 
       on t1.session = t2.session
    WHERE t1.performance = (SELECT MAX(performance) 
                            FROM mytable t3 WHERE t3.session = t1.session)
      AND t2.performance = (SELECT MIN(performance) 
                            FROM mytable t3 WHERE t3.session = t2.session)
```

Now, `mytable` itself is a query which is really long (more than a page). I'm wondering if there is any way to define the query with some constant (what we usually do in Java or C++) to avoid copy-paste the same lines again and again.

Comment: Maybe I did not understood it ok but can you just create a view ?

Comment: I apologize, I am new in sql, what I was trying to say that my final query (when I replace myTable with the exact query I have, it becomes very long) is really long. Any way to keep it short.